# How much XP do I need and what items do you get for each trainer level reached?

Tags: pokemon-go

How much XP do I need and what items do you get for each trainer level reached? If it's not random does anyone know what items you get at each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewards are the same for everyone and can be different per level. For example up to level 4 you get 15 Poke balls and after that you get multiple items. There is a handy table with the [different items and XP required](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Level) for each level.

Remember that leveling up isn't just about the items you get. The key benefit is that you unlock items (also on the table I mentioned above) and can capture higher CP Pokemon.

Comment: You may want to add as much information as you can to your answer from that link, just in case things go south and the website goes down. Then there's a solid backup here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Everyone get the same rewards.

Here you have the first 9 levels rewards list for everyone:

```
Level      Unlockable Rewards
2          Poke Ball x10
3          Poke Ball x15
4          Poke Ball x15
5          Poke Ball x20  Potion x10  Revive x10  Incense
6          Poke Ball x15  Potion x10  Revive x5   Egg Incubator
7          Poke Ball x15  Potion x10  Revive x5   Incense
8          Poke Ball x15  Potion x10  Revive x5   Razz Berry x10  Lure Module
9          Poke Ball x15  Potion x10  Revive x5   Razz Berry x3   Lucky Egg
```

You can see the complete list here: [Level Rewards and Unlockable Items](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items)